# Conversion from image to base64, System.drawing.image

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I use c# for windows phone 8 app and i need to convert one image to base 64. I use this code:

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

but it return this error:
the name and the type of drwing name it isn't exist on the space of the system name, maybe there isn't an assembly reference.

I try to install a ddl, but it's not ok.

Comment: "I try to install a ddl, but it's not ok." - that doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Sorry my english it's not the best. I try to install ddl but i don't have a installation procedure, and i can't trove it.

Comment: by `ddl` do you mean `dll` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you try to use cannot work on Windows Phone, because it uses classes from the `System.Drawing` assembly, which is not available on this platform.

Try with this sample code:

```
public string GetBase64(Image image)
{
    byte[] bytearray;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)image.Source);
        wb.SaveJpeg(ms, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        bytearray = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
}
```