# BinaryReader in VB.NET don't work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iostream

I write a code for save and show photo and check It's height and width befor that but when I added code for recognize width and height when I use "ReadBytes" method It don't save and read my data

```
Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream

            Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
            Dim height As Integer = img.Height
            Dim width As Integer = img.Width
            If Not (height < 201 And width < 201) Then
                Me.HsMsg1.MessageType = MessageType.Error
                Me.HsMsg1.Message = " 200*200"
                Me.HsMsg1.Visible = True
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)

            Dim bytes = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
            Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            imgDemo.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," & base64String
            imgDemo.Visible = True
            Session("bytes") = bytes
```

Comment: Dim bytes  = br.ReadBytes(CInt(fs.Length))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

> Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)

This line advances to the end of the stream. When you later create the BinaryReader, you're starting at the end of stream, and there's nothing left to read!

I don't recall if streams used by the FileUpload control support seeking or not (look at the `CanSeek` property to find out), but if they do you need to use the `Seek()` method to go back to the beginning of the stream. If not, you'll need to [use your `img` variable as the source to create your byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707033/conversion-from-image-to-base64-system-drawing-image)... and that may be the better option anyway.

Comment: Thank for your help :)
I added this code : fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)